# IOS Search for a list of City/ State ONLY

Tags: ios, swift, location, core-location

Is it possible in IOS to input a query in the UISearchBar and return City/ State matches only?

Just like the weather app that comes installed on ios?

I am trying to avoid google libraries as I dont want to be forced to use their maps.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I kind of abandoned project but I think you just need to use google. Once they select the city you can pass that info to iOS map to query further details. Don't think there is a simple clean solution

Comment: Ok, I'm just trying to get a city search without a map going. Thanks for replying!!